# trying to calculate volume of a cone

Tags: matlab, geometry

I'm trying to approximate the volume of a cone with a MATLAB program that uses n equalheight discs(cylinders)  with decreasing radii. The biggest disc on the bottom, the next on top of it, and the one with smallest radii on the top. I have no troubles getting the inputs, but I can't figure out how to calculate the volume with using discs. For loop or while loop?

By the way the volume of a disc is pi*r*r*h, h is height, r is radius

Next step, i need to calculate number of disc needed so that error percentage is less than 1%

This is all i've written so far, it works great calculating the volume with finite number of disc, but i cant figure out how to calculate the number of discs so that error percentage is less than 1%. I would appreciate the help.Thanks!!

```
h=input('Enter height: ');
if (h<=0)
disp('Height must be positive!');
else
r=input('Enter base radius: ');
if (r<=0)
disp('Base radius must be positive!');
else
n=input('Enter number of discs: ');
ne=n;
  while n>0 || n~=0
             if n>0 && (mod(n,1))==0
                Vcone=(1/3)*(pi*r*r*h);
                VTotal=0;
                  for i=n:-1:1
                      rEachDisc=r*(((i-1)*h)/n)/h;
                      VEachDisc=(pi*rEachDisc*rEachDisc)*(h/n);
                      VTotal=VTotal+VEachDisc;                   
                  end
                Vapp=VTotal+((pi*r*r)*(h/n));
                eror=abs((Vcone-Vapp)/Vcone*100);
                fprintf('For n=%g, approximated volume: %g ; error:     %g%%\n',n,Vapp,eror)
             else
                disp('This is not a positive integer!');
             end
        n=input('Enter number of discs: ');
  end 
end
end
VTotal=0;
t=1;
Vcone=(1/3)*(pi*r*r*h);
for i=ne:-1:1
rEachDisc=r*(((i-1)*h)/ne)/h;
VEachDisc=(pi*rEachDisc*rEachDisc)*(h/ne);
VTotal=VTotal+VEachDisc; 
Vapp=VTotal+((pi*r*r)*(h/ne));
eror=abs((Vcone-Vapp)/Vcone*100);
if eror==1
fprintf('We need at least %g discs to approximate the volume with less than 1%%   error.',ne);
  break
end
end
```

Comment: You know the number of discs, so you can use a for loop.

Comment: the only problem is, i only know the biggest disc's radius

Comment: You have n discs with radii r[i] (i=1 top disc to i=n base disc). Now think about: What is the biggest disc's radius (r[n] = ?)? What do you expect for radius r[n/2] or r[n/3]? Going on you'll find a quite simple relation to calculate the radius of the i-th disc r[i] (depending on base radius r and number of discs and i of course). Then you may loop over all discs i and sum up the volumes.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers, especially yoda's tell you how to compute approximations.

As to detect when you've reached the 1% error, there are two options:

- Compare with the exact formula `V = pi/3 * r^2 * h`, where `r` is the base radius. Since this basically eliminates the need for any approximation, this is probably not the idea.
- Consider the following thought experiment:

  - If you take a stack of discs which contains the whole cone (that is, the largest disc should have the base radius as a radius), the volume must be *less* than the sum of the volumes of the discs.
  - If you take a stack of discs contained in the whole cone ("shift the radii by one step"), the volume of the cone must be *more* than the sum of the volumes of the discs.
  - Hence, the error is always less than the difference between the two stacks. If you use the first one as your approximation, the error is less than the largest disc.

In code:

```
r = h*(1:n)/n;
V = pi * r.^2 * h / n;
V = sum(V);
e = V(1);
re = e/(V-e);
```

Now `V` contains an estimate for the volume and `e` an upper bound for the absolute error, and `re` an upper bound for the relative error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

The key is to realise that a cone has a constant slope, so each disc in your approximation of the cone is going to differ from the last one in radius by a constant factor. (Or equivalently, it's going to differ from the last one in diameter by a constant factor. It's the same thing.)

To calculate the radius of each disc, you need to subtract a fixed number from the previous radius. So each time round the loop you will need to modify the radius variable r.

Comment: Thank you both. Actually i am not allowed to use arrays but your approach to the problem lead me to find the answer on my own.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to program if you break the problem down, and you don't have to use any loops at all. MATLAB's strength is in array/vector manipulation, and you should make full use of that. Here are the steps that you should try:

1. First you'll need to partition the cone into `N` pieces. Treating the height as a vector from `0` to `H`, use the [linspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) function to divide it into `N` equal segments.
2. As Robin mentioned, the slope is constant. So find this slope (from height `H` and base radius `R`) and using this and the height vector, you can get the radius radius vector, which gives the radius of each disk.
3. You know how to calculate the area of a single disk. In MATLAB, you can perform arithmetic operations on all the elements in an array using the `.` prefix. So, for e.g., if you were to raise all elements of a vector `x` to some power `n`, you'd write `x.^n`. From this, you can calculate the area of each disk in a single step. No loops required.
4. Use [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html) to add up the areas of the disk.
5. Finally to get the volume, you'll need to multiply this total area by the the thickness of a disk. This you can easily get from the height vector.

Good luck.